# Create Tuple Using List of datatype of string in c#

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I need to create Tuple from list of datatype in string, but did not get any solution.

Here is example of what I want to do.

```
string[] dataType = {"int", "float", "datetime"};

//I want to create list like this but dynamically datatype come from db.
//List<Tuple<int, string, string>> list = new List<Tuple<int, string, string>>(); 

List<Tuple<dataType[0],dataType[1], dataType[2]>> list = new List<Tuple<dataType[0],dataType[1], dataType[2]>>();
//Here datatype value is in string so I want to convert string to actual datatype.
```

Or if any alternative solution for this please guide me.

Comment: You could use `dynamic` as the type

Comment: can please give me example of that.

Comment: Check Tuple.Create, This may solve your problem

Comment: You have ways to create `List<Tuple<dataType[0],dataType[1], dataType[2]>>`, but you can't use the created value as `List<Tuple<dataType[0],dataType[1], dataType[2]>>` in your code. Everything has to be runtime. What do you want to do with the list created?

Comment: Hi @PravinTukadiya, see the answer I posted.

Comment: the answer to your question is: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266963/convert-to-a-datatype-given-in-string-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266963/convert-to-a-datatype-given-in-string-format)

Comment: @weichch my datatype is come from database and it not fixed it based on selection of data.

Comment: @SinaHoseinkhani I have read that link but I can not get that how to implement that solution in my code.

Comment: @Pravin Tukadiya It would help a lot if you extend your question code to show how you actually use your list of tuples (if you are putting something in your list, you probably should/could know the types, even if they come from DB!)

Answer (score 1):

This is to extend my comments under question, and show you what I meant there.

It is not hard to create a list of `Tuple` dynamically from list of types in string format. For example, use reflection:

```
private Type InferType(string typeName)
{
    switch (typeName.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        case "int":
            return typeof(int);
        case "float":
            return typeof(float);
        default:
            return Type.GetType($"System.{typeName}", true, true);
    }
}

private object CreateListOfTupleFromTypes(string[] types)
{
    var elementTypes = types.Select(InferType).ToArray();

    // Get Tuple<,,>
    var tupleDef = typeof(Tuple)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .First(mi => mi.Name == "Create"
            && mi.GetParameters().Count() == elementTypes.Length)
        .ReturnType
        .GetGenericTypeDefinition();

    // Get Tuple<int, float, DateTime>
    var tupleType = tupleDef.MakeGenericType(elementTypes);

    // Get List<Tuple<int, float, DateTime>>
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(tupleType);

    // Create list of tuple.
    var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

    return list;
}
```

The problem is because the list is created using types only known at runtime, in your code, you can never use the list as strong typed list. i.e.`List<Tuple<int, float, DateTime>>`.

Of course, you could make life easier when the list is used in your code by using `ITuple`:

```
var list = new List<ITuple>();
list.Add(new Tuple<int, float, DateTime>(...);

int value1 = (int)list[0][0];
float value1 = (float)list[0][1];
DateTime value1 = (DateTime)list[0][2];
```

However, if you do that, then there is no point to use `Tuple`. You only need `List<object[]>`.

**So, this comes back to my question, what is the list of tuple for in your code?**

Answer (score -1):

You could use `dynamic` here for your types. For example, when you read the three values from your database you could assign them without worrying about the types like so:

```
dynamic a = 10;
dynamic b = "Some String";
dynamic c = new DateTime(2020,4,9);

var test = new System.Tuple<dynamic,dynamic,dynamic>(a, b, c);
```

It would depend on what you want to do with the values later on.

To create a list of those tuples use:

```
var list = new List<System.Tuple<dynamic,dynamic,dynamic>>();
```

You can get the type of the variable, for instance `a` with

```
a.GetType().ToString();
```

I am not sure if you can set a variable type based on a string value, though (the second part of your question).

Comment: The OP is using `System.Tuple` not `ValueTuple`.

Comment: I don't think he is asking for dynamic, but rather want the tuple be of actual types.

Comment: @SinaHoseinkhani, the only way I can think of getting close to that is to write a factory method that returns a variable of that type. You could create a switch statement:

    switch (typeString):
    {
        case "string":
            return string a;
        case "int":
            return int a;
        .... }